# Multiplying a square matrix and its symmetric with a row and column vector from both sides.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, symmetric-matrices

Suppose we have a square $N\times N$ matrix A, its symmetric matrix $ S = {1\over2}(A+A^T)$, and a $N\times 1$ column vector $v$. Why does the expression below hold true?

$v^TAv = v^TSv $

Baically, all i need to show, is that  $v^TAv = v^TA^Tv$, but how can i prove this?

Comment: Let $x =  v^{T} Av$. Since $x$ is a scalar, $x^{T} = x$.

Comment: Now i get it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Except for take $x$ as a scalar, another simple proof.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_N \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}, v = \begin{pmatrix}v_1, \dots, v_N\end{pmatrix}^T$, where $a_i$ is the column vectors of A. Then:

\begin{align}
v^TA^Tv &= 
\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \dots & v_N
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\dots & a_1^T & \dots \\
\dots & a_2^T & \dots \\
 & \vdots & \\
\dots & a_N^T & \dots
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_N
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} v_1 * a_1^T + \dots + v_N * a_n^T
\end{bmatrix}_{1\times N}
\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_N
\end{bmatrix}_{N\times 1} \\
v^TAv &= \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \dots & v_N
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_N \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_N
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \dots & v_N
\end{bmatrix}_{1\times N} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 * a_1 + \dots + v_N * a_n
\end{bmatrix}_{N\times 1} \\
&= \left( \begin{bmatrix} v_1 * a_1^T + \dots + v_N * a_n^T
\end{bmatrix}_{1\times N}
\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_N
\end{bmatrix}_{N\times 1} \right)^T \\
\end{align}

Whatever, it's also obvious that the two scalar $v^TAv = v^TA^Tv$ now. hahah